# I cannot complete command or file name in my cmd using TAB key. What have I modified from default settings?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I cannot complete command or file name in my cmd using the TAB key. When I press TAB it actually inserts a TAB space. What have I modified from default settings?

I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The completion character is configured in Registry. Open `regedit`, navigate to the key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`, and make sure the value `CompletionChar` is set to 9 (0x9). If such a value doesn't exist, add it (right-click - *New* - *DWORD value*) and enter 9 as data.

A possible cause for this is that the *system-wide* settings (`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`) have the completion character set to 64 (0x40) by default, effectively disabling completion unless per-user settings override it. If you want, you can change the system-wide setting to 9 (0x9) too.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm! This is a recent problem, suggesting that something I might have installed or modified changed my system settings.

Comment: @Benny: *user* settings. Although I can't imagine why any program would want to change that. Did you find the value in HKCU gone entirely, or just with a different data?

Comment: The value did not exist at all. I had to create it.

Comment: @grawity This did not work for me. I have checked, both `CompletionChar` and `PathCompletionChar` values are set to 9 in both `HKCU` and `HKLM`. Do you have an idea what might be the reason? I am not able to autocomplete any command with `TAB` key.